Golang Stomp connection using server path
I am trying to connect to a websocket server from a Golang client.  The server is listening on a path, like so:  host:port/path.  The server is expecting a Stomp client to connect and then subscribe to a topic as identified in the stomp headers by "/topic/topic-name".
I have tried both stompngo and go-stomp libraries to accomplish this task, but neither library seems to support making a connection at a path location on the server.
netConn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp","host:9080", 5*time.Second)

does not accept a path to the server
neither
stompConn, err := go-stomp.Connect(netConn)

nor
stompConn,err := stompngo.Connect(netConn, stompngo.Headers{})

allows for a path to be provided on the stomp connection. Unless there is a stompngo.Header I've not found that directs the connection to a path on the server?
As an alternative, I used the gorilla websocket package to make a websocket connection and this library happily supports the connection using a path.  The issue here is that it is not stomp-compliant, so the challenge once connected is figuring out how to write a message to the stream that triggers the subscription on a server that is expecting stomp clients.
Ideally, I can find a way to make a connection to host:port/path using a stomp-compliant library.
Any help appreciated....
